# Return always new list from a function or not?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a public function to a class where that function returns a `List` of item, say List(of employee) for example.

This function will be called frequently from outside this class.

From the memory consumption point of view, is it better to:

1. initialize always new list inside this function, add items to it and return this list or;
2. have a list stored in a field, clear items from it, add new items and return this list

A code example:

1.

```
public List<employee> GetItems()
{
    List<employee> list = new List<employee>();
    list.Add(new employee());
    list.Add(new employee());
    ....
    return list;
}
```

2.

```
private List<employee> _list = new List<employee>();
public List<employee> GetItems()
{
    _list.Clear();
    _list.Add(new employee());
    _list.Add(new employee());
    ...
    return _list;
}
```

Is one of the above more preferred in terms of memory consumption? And in what circumstances one of the above should be used instead of the other option?

Comment: Both seem suspicious - you shouldn't return a mutable collection. Especially in the second case - someone may modify the list and you'll get a different result for different calls. Use `IEnumerable<T>`. Having said that, this seems a bit too broad and opinion based.

Comment: I don't think that `2` is ever expected from an API point of view. Everywhere that has a reference acquired from `GetItems` has its list cleared and reset when another class calls `GetItems`? Bizarre and most likely error-prone. Maybe there's a name that would make this make sense, but I can't think of one. From your example though, maybe you should look into [iterators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx).

Comment: presumably you meant `return _list` in option 2, in which case you are breaking encapsulation. Like the others here I would stay away from that option.

Comment: @BartoszKP If the collection was immutable option two would be impossible.

Comment: @Magnus `public IEnumerable<employee> GetItems()` can safely return `List<employee>` instance as immutable.

Comment: @BartoszKP Not if using the same list and doing Clear/Add in the function.

Comment: @Magnus Regardless of what are you doing with the list (even if it's stupid, like in this example) you can return it as `IEnumerable<T>`, as I've stated.

Comment: @BartoszKP yes, but it is only immutable to callers. If you change the list that might break the usage of it from previous callers.

Comment: @Magnus Never said it wouldn't. You *should* use `IEnumerable<T>` nevertheless. Fixing the problems you've indicated is also a must, of course.

Comment: @BartoszKP If one want immutability and the underlying structure is `List<T>` I would probably rather go with `IReadonlyList<T>`

Comment: @eisenpony -> I fixed the typo. Option 2 should return _list.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second option will use less memory. Potentially a *lot* less (due to some behavior you may not have considered yet).

The first sample returns an actual new object to the caller. Since the local variable immediately goes out of scope, the lifetime of the object will be determined by the caller. So it will use more memory because more objects are created, and even if they are quickly destroyed, the GC won't collect them right away.

The second option only ever has the one object, and thus uses less memory. **However** this means that all callers will be pointing *to the same object*. So each time you clear and add, it effects **all previous callers** unless they made a copy. Additionally, a large threading hazard exists if multiple threads use this class.

The second option, while it uses less memory, is *extremely* dangerous code, and I would be very hesitant about using it.

Comment: This is false. The truth is that *both options will use the same amount of memory*, since it is not the list itself that consumes memory, but *individually allocated items* are consuming memory. The actual list will roughly take-up `sizeof(reference) * itemCount`, which is negligible compared to the size of `Employee` instance. Given that both options always create new `Employee`s, both will use the same amount of memory given the same consumers.

Comment: @BorisB. Not true at all, while the size of the list may be negligible, it is *not* 0. Also, the first option will likely create more `Employee` objects that persist, as unless something else holds references to them individually, they get collected sometime after `Clear`. I totally agree that memory is the least of the concerns with this code, but the second will almost certainly use less (by some amount).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Although it will lead to larger memory fragmentation.

Comment: @BartoszKP No doubt about that.

Answer (score 4):

Never do option two. Remember that you are returning the same reference. So while you are clearing the list, someone else might for example be trying to iterate it. And that will cause exceptions. 
Also after you have returned the list you can't control what others are doing to it, for example adding/removing items will effect all callers who got the list from the function.

Answer (score 1):

Those two examples aren't equivalent. In the second example, you will be returning a reference to the same list.

The first method will always return a unique object, which is presumably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the respondents stated, select choice 1. Also as @BartoszKP stated, I would probably return IEnumerable. You can save yourself a few keystrokes by shortcutting the initialization. You can express the code as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<employee> GetItems()
{
  return new List<employee> { 
    new employee("Alan"),
    new employee("Bob"),  
    new employee("Carla")
  }; 
}
```